# JQuery DataTable - Server-side processing not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

EDIT: Without hard-coding `sEcho`

[image]

EDIT:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <h3 class="panel-heading">Information</h3>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="dt_vendor">
              <table id="dt_vendor">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have got a JSON object that I receive from a .Net, the JSON object is created as per the specified format. But I do not see that its loading the data and I have checked in the Chrome console and I do not see any errors I have got over 15,000 records, what I'm missing and I know it must be very silly

The JSON Object :

[image]

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dt_vendor").dataTable({    

            "oLanguage": {
                "sZeroRecords": "No records to display",
                "sSearch": "Search..."
            },
            'iDisplayLength': 10,
            "lengthMenu": [ 5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100 ],
            "bSortClasses": false,
            "bStateSave": false,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("GetAjaxData", "Vendor")",
           "bJQueryUI": true,
           "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
           "bDeferRender": true,

           "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
               debugger;
               $.ajax({
                   "dataType": 'json',
                   "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   "type": "GET",
                   "url": sSource,
                   "aadata": aoData,
                   "success":
                               function (msg) 
                               {    
                                   var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                                   fnCallback(json);
                                   $("#dt_vendor").show();
                               }
               });
           }

        }); 

        }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer**

Here are a couple of thoughts for your debugging:

- Are you hard-coding the value of "sEcho" or returning the value provided? DataTable uses that to make sure it's processing the response to its latest request.
- Try providing an empty <tbody> tag inside the <table> simply to ensure that it exists.

**Solution**

Make sure that the value of `sEcho` included in the response from the .NET code is the same as the value of `sEcho` provided in the request to the .NET code.

Comment: I'm hardcoding the `sEcho` should I not? and also I have tried with adding `<tbody>` inside the table but still the same.

Comment: No, do not hard-code `sEcho`. Return the value you receive for `sEcho`. DataTable sends a unique value for `sEcho` each time it makes a request and expects the response to have the same value in `sEcho`.

Comment: I did take out hard-coding of `sEcho` but does not make any difference same please see my updated question a screen shot

Comment: Ok... It's still essentially the same problem. Your server-side code is receiving a variable called `sEcho`. You need to return `sEcho`, but it should be the value received by the server-side code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last post.

Comment: Your .NET code receives a set of URL variables (`GET` in some languages). It doesn't appear that you're sending it any of your own, but DataTable sends it `sEcho`, `iSortCol1`, `iSortCol2`, `sSortDir1`, `sSortDir2`, `sSortDir3`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for checking out, sorry did not help your answer

Comment: Let's say you're storing your response in a variable called `Response`. You would simply add a line of code that reads `Response.sEcho = Request.sEcho` so it's responding with the same value of `sEcho` that it received.

Comment: @AbuHamzah Correction to previous comment: Depending on how you're sending the request, you'll want to add `Response.sEcho = Request.QueryString.sEcho` if GET or `Response.sEcho = Request.Form.sEcho` if POST.